# Generating a sequence of equidistant points on polygon boundary

Tags: r, geometry, r-sp

I am looking for a procedure that allows me to generate a sequence of equidistant points (coordinates) along the sides of an arbitrary polygon.

Imaging a polygon defined by the coordinates of its vertexes:

```
poly.mat <- matrix(c(0,0,
                   0,1,
                   0.5,1.5,
                   0.5,0,
                   0,0 # last row included to close the polygon
                   ), byrow = T, ncol = 2)
colnames(poly.mat) <- c("x", "y")
plot(poly.mat, type = "l")
```

If the length of the sequence I want to generate is `n` (adjustable), how I can produce a sequence, starting at (0,0), of equidistant coordinates.

I got as far as calculating the perimeter of the shape with the `geosphere` package (which I believe I need)

```
library(geosphere)
n <- 50 # sequence of length set to be 50
perim <- perimeter(poly.mat)
perim/n # looks like every section needs to be 8210.768 something in length
```

Comment: equidistant each from the next? Straight distance or traveling along the boundary?

Comment: Equidistant each from the next, yes. Traveling along the boundary.

Comment: so, you want to unwind the polygon perimeter and break it into equal segments? or you want equally spaced points between each vertex

Comment: and you want to end up where you started, it seems.

Comment: that perimeter looks wrong. way too big. the actual perimeter is `1 + 1.5 + .5 + .5 * sqrt(2)`

Comment: The first, I think. Basically, it should be a procedure that walks the path of the boundary, stops after it has reached some distance from the last point and then retrieves the current coordinates. The length of every section on the path should be the same.

Comment: what you want is a parametric equation traversing the polygon boundary, i.e. `x(t)` and `y(t)` for, e.g., `t` along `0:1` giving the x- and y-coordinates as a function of a single dimension. then you can just plug in `(x(0), y(0))`, `(x(1/n), y(1/n))`, ..., `(x(1), y(1))`.

Comment: perimeter from geosphere wants latitude/longitude coordinates, not Cartesian. You could find the perimeter yourself by adding side lengths found from the distance formula.

Comment: I think first you want to find the length of each side (so you calculate those only once), and add those up as you go along to find perimeter, and store those running totals too, so that when you want to see where you are when you have traveled a distance d (0 <=d<=P), you can quickly find which side that would be on (because d>= the distance at some corner P  and <=  at the next, call it Q), how much distance must be traveled along that side (d  - total at P), and what fraction of PQ that is (so you can then get coordinates by P+fraction*(Q-P)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with.

```
pointDistance <- function(p1, p2){
  sqrt((p2[,1]-p1[,1])^2) + sqrt((p2[,2]-p1[,2])^2)
}

getPos <- function(shp.mat, ll){
  greaterLL <- shp.mat$cumdis > ll
  if(all(greaterLL == FALSE)) return(poly.mat[nrow(poly.mat), c("x", "y")])
  smallRow <- min(which(greaterLL)) # the smallest coordinate that has greater length
  p.start <- shp.mat[smallRow-1, c("x","y")]
  p.end <- shp.mat[smallRow, c("x","y")]
  cumVal <- shp.mat$cumdis[smallRow]
  prop <- (ll-shp.mat$cumdis[smallRow-1])/(shp.mat$cumdis[smallRow]-shp.mat$cumdis[smallRow-1])

  p.start + (prop)* (p.end-p.start)
}

# shp1
poly.mat <- matrix(c(0,0,
                 0,1,
                 0.5,1.5,
                 0.5,0,
                 0,0
),byrow = T, ncol = 2)
colnames(poly.mat) <- c("x", "y")
poly.mat <- as.data.frame(poly.mat)


# Main fun
pointsOnPath <- function(shp.mat, n){

dist <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = nrow(shp.mat)-1)

for(i in 2:nrow(shp.mat)){
  dist[i] <- pointDistance(p1 = shp.mat[i,], p2 = shp.mat[i-1,])
}
shp.mat$dist <- dist
shp.mat$cumdis <- cumsum(shp.mat$dist)


dis <- matrix(seq(from = 0, to = max(shp.mat$cumdis), length.out = n+1), ncol = 1)

out <- lapply(dis, function(x) getPos(shp.mat = shp.mat, ll = x))
out <- do.call("rbind", out)
out$dis <- dis

out[-nrow(out),]
}

df <- pointsOnPath(shp.mat = poly.mat, 5)

# Plot
plot(poly.mat$x, poly.mat$y, type = "l", xlim = c(0,1.5), ylim = c(0,1.5))
points(df$x, df$y, col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

[image: pointsonpath-plot]

There is room for improving the code, but it should return the correct result

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write the code yourself.  Sorry, there isn't a library function for every last detail of every last assignment.  Assuming that each pair of points defines a line segment, you could just generate N points along each segment, as in

begin = [xbegin, ybegin ];
end   = [xend, yend ];

xdist = ( xend - xbegin ) / nintervals;
ydist = ( yend - ybegin ) / nintervals;

then your points are given by [ xbegin + i * xdist, ybegin + i * ydist ]